# Previous form item with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of form items - a name and a checkbox to delete the item.

```
<input value="www…" name="web[]" type="text" class="siteName"/>
<input name="delete" type="checkbox" value="delete" class="delete"/>
```

I created this to swap the field values between the two items so that the text field is emptied but the value is stored in the checkbox should it be mistaken.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function () { 
    $('.delete').change(function(){
        var oldVal = $('.siteName').val();
        $('.siteName').val($(this).val());
        $(this).val(oldVal);
    });
});
</script>
```

If there are multiple groups of form items all are altered, can I set it so that the previous ".siteName" form item is the only one changed (I tried .prev() to no avail but not use how to use it correctly). I could easily make multiple instances of the script and number the class names but I'd have thought there would be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes ..using `this` reference and `prev()`

```
$('.delete').change(function(){
    var siteEle=$(this).prev();
    var oldVal = siteEle.val();
    siteEle.val($(this).val());
    $(this).val(oldVal);
});
```

or closest()

```
$('.delete').change(function(){
    var siteEle=$(this).closest('.siteName');
    var oldVal = siteEle.val();
    siteEle.val($(this).val());
    $(this).val(oldVal);
});
```

`closest()` might not give you right values if incase the siteName input starts right next to the checkbox again.. so if you are sure the previous element is input class siteName then `prev()` is better

Comment: Thanks - this was almost exactly what I'd tried and what didn't work, however as you said the same I persevered and found that as I'd wrapped the checkbox in a label tag - IT was making the script not work for some reason

Comment: yup...that is beacuse you previous element will be label..and will not be able to find the `val()` of that... anyways glad you figured it out urself... and glad it helped...happy coding

Comment: thing is I'd had the script saying .prev('.siteName'), so thought it should have just found the previous instance of that class - thought it was odd. Never mind got it working.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () { 
    $('.delete').change(function(){
        var $myPrevSiteName = $(this).prev('.siteName');
        var oldVal = $myPrevSiteName.val();
        $myPrevSiteName.val( this.value );
        $(this).val(oldVal);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks - this was almost exactly what I'd tried and what didn't work, however as you said the same I persevered and found that as I'd wrapped the checkbox in a label tag - IT was making the script not work for some reason

Answer (score 1):

I think I didn't quit understand you're question, but let me try are you're trying to achieve something like this

http://jsbin.com/ajavul/2/edit

instead of using prev() I wrapped each of the input and check boxes in a parent tag, on which I then apply you're given jquery code with some little changes. If this is not what you've tried to achieve please provide me some more information.

Comment: that's a nice solution - what the other guys did worked so had that integrated a while back. Thanks